# Did Howard Hughes store his urine in Mason jars?

Tags: celebrities

In the 2004 film [The Aviator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Aviator_%282004_film%29), a biography of [Howard Hughes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howard_Hughes), it depicts the reclusive billionaire storing his own urine in mason jars in a screening room. Is this true? Note that the linked Wikipedia article also makes an (unsourced) statement about this.

Comment: This claim is also repeated, without reference, in the Wikipedia article itself (which I think is more notable than a movie).

Comment: Answer: Yes, according to page 426 of "Howard Hughes: His Life and Madness" by Donald Barlett. https://books.google.com/books?id=ivZGrgLszbcC&lpg=PA679&ots=oblrpCPlsT&pg=PA426#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @BlueCollar I added your contribution to my answer. I know that comments usually disappear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**There is an overwhelming consensus of 'Yes he did.'**

According to [Howard Hughes: The Secret Life by Charles Higham (1993)](https://books.google.com.qa/books?id=xW6zAAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover):

- Page 121 describes the great lengths he had people go to accomodate
  him.

  > He had a team of engineers work around the clock to design a more comfortable bed for him in moving sections with an aperture and a pipe to conduct out urine and feces.
- Page 191 describes his fear of touching dirty objects.

  > He didn't risk turning the doorknob, even with gloves. He would kick the door as a signal and the drivers would open it. He was obsessed with the toilet. He urinated on the floor; then he covered it with Kleenexes to sop up the fluid. He refused to let his men use the toilet; instead they had to use empty ice buckets.
- By page 247, and further descent into mental illness, describes the Mason jars.

  > His fondness for Empirin and mainlining codeine had affected his kidneys; and his fear of anyone's seeing his urine still compelled him to bottle it in Mason jars.

**Contrary statements do exist.**

According to Jim Whetton, when asked by the [Standard Examiner](http://www.standard.net/Education/2014/10/18/Howard-Hughes-associate-to-speak-at-WSU) about Hughes' urine collection, he responded with:

> “He never did such a thing,” Whetton said. “The man was a recluse, period. That’s it.”

**Conclusion**

There are way more books, and media publications, that describe Howard Hughes' treatment of his urine. One [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=does%20the%20catholic%20church%20own%2020%25%20of%20italy&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=howard%20hughes%20urine) can confirm that. According to page 426 of "[Howard Hughes: His Life and Madness](https://books.google.com.qa/books?id=ivZGrgLszbcC&lpg=PA679&ots=oblrpCPlsT&pg=PA426&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)" by Donald Barlett - Hughes *did* (Credit: [Bluecollar](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/29113/bluecollar)). Jim Whetton, although a great friend and colleague, seems to be alone in his defense of the urine behavior. Could Jim be simply trying to maintain a positive legacy for a lost friend? Possibly yes. Could many authors of various publications simply be exaggerating the urine incidents as a part of an extravagant scheme to show that Howard Hughes - the rich and powerful - had a flaw? Possibly yes.

Comment: `his fear of anyone's seeing his urine still compelled him to bottle it in Mason jars.` Aren't Mason jars transparent though?

Comment: @MarchHo +1. His rationale _possibly_ was he could put the Mason jars somewhere else, maybe?